# How to use git graph in vs code?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, graph, git-branch, git-commit

I am doing a git course and the git graph extension has been recommended to me.
To my colleagues, the extension shows a graph with the different branches as follows:

[image: git_grapg1]

But to me all the branches appear in the same line:

[image: git_graph2]

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong or how to use the extension. Thank you very much.

Comment: you are doing nothing wrong, if you don't have merge commits it is a straight line, I prefer it that way

Comment: I am a little confused. Actually if I have done "merge" between two branches with "git merge hobbies" being in master. In that case, shouldn't I go out like my classmates? Thank you"

Comment: most likely they are fast-forward merges, when there is no commit done on master git does a fast-forward merge

Comment: You're right. It is a fast-forward merges. I honestly did not know the concept, you have made me learn something new. THANK YOU!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your colleagues' screen shows a real merge commit. Yours seems to be a [*fast-forward merge*](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#_fast_forward_merge). Fast-forward merges are the default when the branches have not diverged. In that case, the branch label can simply be moved to match the other branch's label (i.e. fast-forwarded). Only when branches have diverged, Git must create a merge commit to reconcile the history of both branches.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the **--graph** option

```
git log --oneline --all --graph
```

in **vs code** you can install the extension : [image]

**there are two ways to merge:**

- fast forward merge: **linear graph**
- three-way merge: commit has **diverged** from the master

try to use this command when you need to merge the branch in the master => **disable fast forward (ff)** merge:

```
git merge --no-ff newBranch
```